# How to write a method that finds the most common letter in a string?

Tags: ruby, string, methods

This is the question prompt:

> Write a method that takes in a `string`. Your method should return the most common letter in the array, and a count of how many times it appears.

I'm not entirely sure where to go with what I have so far.

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  arr1 = string.chars
  arr2 = arr1.max_by(&:count)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use a counting hash:

```
str = "The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox."

str.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/,'').
             each_char.
             with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }.
             max_by(&:last)
   #=> ["e",4]
```

[Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with an argument of zero creates an empty hash whose default value is zero.

The steps:

```
s = str.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/,'')
  #=> "thequickbrowndogjumpedoverthelazyfox"
enum0 = s.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "thequickbrowndogjumpedoverthelazyfox":each_char>  
enum1 = enum0.with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #    "thequickbrowndogjumpedoverthelazyfox":each_char>:with_object({})>
```

You can think of `enum1` as a "compound" enumerator. (Study the return value above.)

Let's see the elements of `enum1`:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["t", {}], ["h", {}], ["e", {}], ["q", {}],..., ["x", {}]]
```

The first element of `enum1` (`["t", {}]`) is passed to the block by [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) and assigned to the block variables:

```
c,h = enum1.next
  #=> ["t", {}] 
c #=> "t" 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is then performed:

```
h[c] += 1
  #=> h[c] = h[c] + 1
  #=> h["t"] = h["t"] + 1
  #=> h["t"] = 0 + 1 #=> 1
h #=> {"t"=>1}
```

Ruby expands `h[c] += 1` to `h[c] = h[c] + 1`, which is `h["t"] = h["t"] + 1` As `h #=> {}`, `h` has no key `"t"`, so `h["t"]` on the right side of the equal sign is replaced by the hash's default value, `0`. The next time `c #=> "t"`, `h["t"] = h["t"] + 1` will reduce to `h["t"] = 1 + 1 #=> 2` (i.e., the default value will not be used, as `h` now has a key `"t"`).

The next value of `enum1` is then passed into the block and the block calculation is performed:

```
c,h = enum1.next
  #=> ["h", {"t"=>1}] 
h[c] += 1
  #=> 1 
h #=> {"t"=>1, "h"=>1}
```

The remaining elements of `enum1` are processed similarly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do that, without worrying about checking empty letters:

```
letter, count = ('a'..'z')
                .map {|letter| [letter, string.count(letter)] }
                .max_by(&:last)
```

Comment: It works, but how can I get the number of times this letter appears?

Comment: Oh, that's a fast one!

Comment: @Kirill, no, it's a slow one.  It makes 26 passes through the entire string when only one is needed (certainly much slower than your solution).

Comment: Yes, it's a much slower, though direct, solution.

Comment: That's strange. I [did simple benchmark](https://gist.github.com/kirillzh/d4a758dab4b68ce0c1c1) and your solution is faster than mine.

Comment: Wow, that's weird! The difference is 3 orders of magnitude! But I think I know what's happening: your solution takes too much time on long strings by splitting them up. If you try shorter strings, there's almost no difference in time. I'll analyse the complexity of both algorithms tomorrow with more attention. I've learned a lesson here: sometimes the simplest algorithm, although at first sight seemingly slower, performs better due to hidden complexity. Even I jumped to conclusions without proper benchmarking. Congratulations for the scientific method, @Kirill Zhukov. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  string.downcase.split('').group_by(&:itself).map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.max_by(&:last)
end
```

**Edit:**
Using hash:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  chars             = {}
  most_common       = nil
  most_common_count = 0
  string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').each_char do |c|
    count = (chars[c] = (chars[c] || 0) + 1)
    if count > most_common_count
      most_common       = c
      most_common_count = count
    end
  end
  [most_common, most_common_count]
end
```

Comment: Good answer, once you fix a wee problem: `most_common_letter("          a           ") #=> [" ", 21]` (SO scrunched most of my spaces. As you see, there are 21.) Not just spaces, of course: `most_common_letter("She--Ann--is very cool") #=> ["-", 4] `.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, that's odd. I am getting `most_common_letter(" a ") #=> [" ", 2]`. What's wrong with `most_common_letter("She--Ann--is very cool") #=> ["-", 4]`?

Comment: Also, how can I get rid off `res` variable?

Comment: The characters `" "` and `"-"` are not letters.  Letters are `"a"-"z"` and `"A"-"Z"`.  See my answer for ideas. You could eliminate `res` with: `str.split('').group_by(&:itself).map { |k,v| [k,v.size] }.max_by(&:last)`.

Comment: You are getting `most_common_letter(" a ") #=> [" ", 2]` because you are copying what I have in my comment. My string had 10 spaces followed by an`"a"`, followed by 11 spaces. In formatting text in comments, however, SO removes excess white space, so it looked like my string had only two spaces.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing what you want:

```
str = 'aaaabbbbcd'
h = str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
max = h.values.max
output_hash = Hash[h.select { |k, v| v == max}]
puts "most_frequent_value: #{max}"
puts "most frequent character(s): #{output_hash.keys}"
```

Comment: Sorting is an extremely inefficient way to find the largest or smallest value of a function defined on a collection.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have updated my answer. What do you think now? Please let me know!

Comment: Much better.  Also, it's the only solution that returns all values with the maximum count in the event of ties (though that wasn't asked for). There are things you can do to tighten it up and make it more Ruby-like. For example, you could drop the second line and write `str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }` (which returns `h`). Notice that I used `each_char` (returns an enumerator) rather than `chars` to avoid the construction of a temporary array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to mention a solution with [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), introduced by **Ruby 2.7.0**:

```
str =<<-END
Tallies the collection, i.e., counts the occurrences of each element. Returns a hash with the elements of the collection as keys and the corresponding counts as values.
END

str.scan(/[a-z]/).tally.max_by(&:last)
#=> ["e", 22]
```

---

Where:

```
str.scan(/[a-z]/).tally
#=> {"a"=>8, "l"=>9, "i"=>6, "e"=>22, "s"=>12, "t"=>13, "h"=>9, "c"=>11, "o"=>11, "n"=>11, "u"=>5, "r"=>5, "f"=>2, "m"=>2, "w"=>1, "k"=>1, "y"=>1, "d"=>2, "p"=>1, "g"=>1, "v"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char, count = string.split('').                  
                     group_by(&:downcase).
                     map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.
                     max_by { |_, v| v }
```